# What does Silverligtht 4.0 Trusted Mode mean on a Mac?

Tags: silverlight, security, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

Are there any special considerations we will need to take into account for Mac scenarios?  Furthermore, with features such as COM interop which aren't applicable on a Mac, how do you give visibility of these capabilities to your code?

```
if (Silverlight.Environment.SupportsCOMInterop) {
   // do stuff
}
```

More generally, could your code determine whether it's running on a Mac or Windows?

Comment: [This blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx) gives an overview of what's new with trusted applications. Can you clarify your question about Macs?

Answer (score 0):

According to the LIVE speak afterwards (approx. 2h ago): besides the lack of COM (obviously) Trusted Mode on Mac should be equivalent to the TM on Windows (access to hardware/cam/keyboard/file-system).

Answer (score 0):

Shawn Wildermuth gave a talk last night in Atlanta and he discussed some of the potential compatability issues with the Elevated Trust (*not* Full Trust) on the Mac.  He mentioned that Drag-and-Drop support is going to be difficult because of the way Safari/Firefox (can't remember which one) is used to run out-of-browser on the mac.  HTML embedding on the Mac might also be an issue.  Shawn is speaking at notatpdc.com tonight about SL4 features.  You might want to attend and ask: http://www.notatpdc.com/Schedule/Detail/20 (note, time is *central* time).